# Unity particles rendering on top of camera space UI

Tags: unity, rendering, gui, particles, draw-order

I'm using LWRP in Unity 2019.1.12f1. The UI is in Screen Space - Camera. The shader used for the particles is Lightweight Render Pipeline/Particles/Unlit (Transparent, Premultiply).

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: If you don't want items in your scene to draw over your UI ever, why use Screen Space - Camera rather than Screen Space - Overlay?

Comment: I want post processing to affect the UI. That doesn't work with Screen Space - Overlay.

Comment: So then you adjusted the plane distance of your UI Canvas to put it closer than the particles, or set its sorting layer to draw over the particles? Show us what you tried and why it's not working for this situation.

Comment: According to this - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GDePoHGMngJ-S0Da0Fi0Ky8jPxYkQD5AkVFnoxlknUY/edit# - "Users need to create a ScriptableRenderPass and inject in LWRP code to render things that require different camera matrices/fov. These vary on a case by case scenario, f.ex, rendering weapons in an FPS." I don't believe there is a straightforward way to achieve this right now. You may try to decrease `Plane Distance` on the `Canvas` until particles can't get in-between canvas and camera.

Comment: Camera stacking is on the road-map but I wouldn't expect it to be released soon. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J8ChJIsAXdXdmOPtNF_FIqd9exYD0kql/view .

Comment: try to add ZTest Always to your UI Shader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increasing order in layer solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Camera Stacks are now part of Unity's Universal Render Pipeline (URP). You can add an overlay camera over your main scene camera to render the particles - https://bdts.com.au/tips-and-resources/unity-ui-particles-in-urp-using-overly-cameras-and-camera-stacks.html